# Getting Error While Requesting Access Token by Authorization Code in Window Live in Asp.net

Tags: window, live

I am working on a Window Live Authentication. I have used the code from GitHub

My Process is
After Login into the Window Live (Hotmail.com)
It will give us one Authorization code which then we send it with the other detail to get the Access Token.

/*
e.g. Url to get the Access token by the Authorization code
https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf?client_id=XXredirect_uri=XX&client_secret=XX&code=7df98b56-0fe5-6898-44ed-5feb8d28f582&grant_type=authorization_code
*/

But I am facing the Error in Getting the Access token from the Authorization code

"The Error is : invalid_grant The provided value for the 'code' parameter is not valid. The code has expired."

Please help me.

Thank you
Vijay Chavda